# FasterXML Jackson: Deserialize json strings that are different?

Tags: java, json

I have an issue with Jackson, I can receive the two following JSON strings:

```
{"resp":{}}
```

Here is the other response.

```
{"resp":{"seg":[]}}
```

Here is the code I'm using but it breaks:

```
for(JsonNode node : json.get("resp").get("seg")) {
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error as on some of the strings I receive do not have the "seg" field. How would one go about to deserialize this?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was thinking maybe Jackson had some inbuilt function to prevent me creating an if clause, if not however I shall continue to check for null!

Comment: Well, you're not really using Jackson to its full potential. You could easily create an actual `Object` that has an `Optional<Segment> segment` property. Jackson [JDK 8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) module will do this automatically. If you insist on using a `Map` then there is no other approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use databindings;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class FooTest {

    private static final String NO_SEG = "{\"resp\":{}}";
    private static final String WITH_SEG = "{\"resp\":{\"seg\": []}}";

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void noSeg() throws IOException {
        final Bar bar = MAPPER.readValue(NO_SEG, Bar.class);

        assertTrue(bar.getResp().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void withSeg() throws IOException {
        final Bar bar = MAPPER.readValue(WITH_SEG, Bar.class);

        assertFalse(bar.getResp().isEmpty());
        assertTrue(bar.getResp().get("seg").isEmpty());
    }

    private static class Bar {
        @JsonProperty("resp")
        private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> resp;

        public Bar() {
        }

        public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> getResp() {
            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```